# Difference between 'pent' and 'pent up'

Tags: vocabulary

I was wondering what is the difference between `pent` and `pent up`.
Because google translate different explanation and translation to both of them i was wondering if there is any difference considering that they are both adjectives
``.

Comment: *Pent* is the past participle of *pen* and is little used these days, except in the phrase "pent-up".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never actually seen **pent** used on its own, only as part of **pent-up**. Some dictionaries contain it, generally agreeing that **pent** is just a contraction of **pent-up**. So there is no difference; use **pent-up** in most cases.

The term originated as another spelling of **penned up**, referring to feelings being held back as if in a pen.

Comment: And make each prisoner pent
Unwillingly represent
A source of innocent merriment!